# Activiti 5.18.0 on Postgres won't use the schema

Tags: postgresql, activiti

Has anyone worked around the problem that Activiti (5.18.0, and I tried the 6 beta, too) won't use the database schema resp. table prefix on Postgres?

On startup, it will not find the tables, if they aren't in the public schema (or another schema that's in the search_path). After that I think it's ok.

There seem to be two bug reports, but that issue doesn't seem solved.

- https://activiti.atlassian.net/browse/ACT-1708
- https://activiti.atlassian.net/browse/ACT-1968

I tried different solutions, one of them was setting the search_path for the database with activiti as its first entry, but it seems that parts of a Postgres library used change the search_path dynamically, so that sooner or later Activiti will complain again.

I'm talking about the integration of the Activiti ProcessEngine in my own application.

Comment: You could create a separate user and change the search_path only for that user. Then make Activity connect with that username. Your application can continue to use a different search_path then

Comment: The method described by a_horse_with_no_name is how we handle this scenario.

Comment: Great idea, thanks! What about transactions then? I tried using a second database, but then I had problems with XA transactions. Ok, that's not comparable, but at least I'd need a second datasource / connection. I'll try it out...

Comment: I'm in a stateless EJB with the ProcessEngine injected, having its own datasource (programmatic config). Any more hints on that TX question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the source code of Activity (actually, I cloned https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti (yesterday!?) and used the branch activiti6) I found that I was actually lacking an attribute.

So if you set the schema **and** the prefix, then you have to set the "tablePrefixIsSchema" attribute to "true"!

```
    processEngineConfiguration.setDatabaseSchema("activiti");
    processEngineConfiguration.setDatabaseTablePrefix("activiti.");
    /**
     * NOTE!
     * 
     * If we set the prefix (for whatever reasons) and it's the same as the
     * schema, then the following attribute has to be set to "true"!!!
     */
    processEngineConfiguration.setTablePrefixIsSchema(true);
```

This solved the whole issue.

I'll try now with Activiti 5.18 and update this solution. (I use Postgresql 9.3 and the driver 9.3-1103-jdbc41.)

The original error was (if others run into this):

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Activiti database problem: Tables missing for component(s) engine, history, identity
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaCheckVersion(DbSqlSession.java:925)
```

Comment: But admittedly, this doesn't at all solve the problem of Activiti not using the schema that was set, in all its queries - so this doesn't help in the long run. Activiti does indeed seem to use the prefix reliably in all places (if you look at their MyBatis entity XMLs), so setting the prefix and the schema and that extra attribute, should - in theory - be the safe way to go.

Comment: Ok, there is simply a bug in the Job.xml DB mapping, where they forgot the prefix, in version 5.18.0. It's fixed on 3rd June 2015 in the activiti6 branch.